# Research help: Path finding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, path-finding

Not a technical question, just asking for a point in the right direction for my research.

Are there any models that address the following problem:

Finding the route starting from X that passes through A, B, C in the most efficient order. In the case below, X,A,C,B is the optimum path (12).

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is CS theory, so try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: interesting. Pretty close to what i'm looking for except for that it returns to the origin city.

Comment: @WillDonaghy This does not change the complexity of the problem, and is still considered a variant of TSP. The solution is pretty much the same to this variant.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look at traveling salesman. There are a lot of resources for how to implement this as it is a very common programming problem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) in Python:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    required=('A', 'B', 'C')
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if start not in graph:
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                if all(e in newpath for e in required):
                    paths.append(newpath)
    return paths       

def min_path(graph, start, end):
    paths=find_all_paths(graph,start,end)
    mt=10**99
    mpath=[]
    print '\tAll paths:',paths
    for path in paths:
        t=sum(graph[i][j] for i,j in zip(path,path[1::]))
        print '\t\tevaluating:',path, t
        if t<mt: 
            mt=t
            mpath=path

    e1=' '.join('{}->{}:{}'.format(i,j,graph[i][j]) for i,j in zip(mpath,mpath[1::]))
    e2=str(sum(graph[i][j] for i,j in zip(mpath,mpath[1::])))
    print 'Best path: '+e1+'   Total: '+e2+'\n'  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    graph = {'X': {'A':5, 'B':8, 'C':10},
             'A': {'C':3, 'B':5},
             'C': {'A':3, 'B':4},
             'B': {'A':5, 'C':4}}
    min_path(graph,'X','B')
```

Prints:

```
    All paths: [['X', 'A', 'C', 'B'], ['X', 'C', 'A', 'B']]
        evaluating: ['X', 'A', 'C', 'B'] 12
        evaluating: ['X', 'C', 'A', 'B'] 18
Best path: X->A:5 A->C:3 C->B:4   Total: 12
```

The 'guts' is recursively finding all paths and filtering to only those paths that visit the required nodes `('A', 'B', 'C')`. The paths are then summed up to find the minimum path expense.

There are certainly be *more efficient* approaches but it is hard to be simpler. You asked for a model, so here is a working implementation.

Comment: This (1) Does not answer the question (which does not ask how to implement it) (2) not efficient (there is significantly more efficient solution) (3) code without explanation answer, which has very little value imo.

Comment: @amit: Thanks for the feedback. The OP asked for Dijkstra's path finding algorithm. This is Dijkstra's algorithm. He did not ask for *the most efficient*. -- just a model. I have added explanation, but the wikipedia entry on Dijkstra's algorithm is significantly better than what someone will find here.

Comment: this is not Dijkstra's algorithm, if it was it would not solve the problem which is TSP, not point to point shortest path.